# Saving selected feature (polygon) as image from shapefile using C#?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in

I am new to ArcGIS and trying a do following things..

```
1) Select polygon in the loaded shapefile.(right click on polygon -> choose option  (select features).

2) Click button (build as Add-in) in C# on the toolbar and selected polygon save as image at specific location.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do what you want is to load the shapefile in your mxd. Symbolize it and zoom to the scale you want, then export the map's active view. There is a code sample here that you can use:

[Esri Sample: Export active view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000026000000)